# Python Regex Problems

Tags: python, regex

I am having trouble converting a RegEx expression to python. I know that `'(\\d+)'` is the expression for a single integer, but I cannot figure out how to get an integer that is [2-9].

The RegEx expression is as follows:

```
[2-9][p-z][a-h][2-9][a-z]*[p-z][2-9][p-z][2-9][p-z]
```

This is my current expression but it produces many false positives as it is not specific enough:

> ```
>           re1='(\\d+)'    # Integer Number 1
>             re2='([a-z])'   # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 1
>             re3='([a-z])'   # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 2
>             re4='(\\d+)'    # Integer Number 2
>             re5='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))' # Word 1
>             re6='(\\d+)'    # Integer Number 3
>             re7='([a-z])'   # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 3
>             re8='(.)'   # Any Single Character 1
>             re9='([a-z])'   # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 4
> ```

```
            ## Regex search for passcodes ## Thanks to Pierluigi Failla
            rg = re.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6+re7+re8+re9,re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
            m = rg.search(txt)
            if m:
                int1=m.group(1)
                w1=m.group(2)
                w2=m.group(3)
                int2=m.group(4)
                word1=m.group(5)
                int3=m.group(6)
                w3=m.group(7)
                c1=m.group(8)
                w4=m.group(9)
                txt2='"'+int1+w1+w2+int2+word1+int3+w3+c1+w4+'"'
                return [txt2]
```

Comment: But `[2-9]` is correct for matching an integer that is 2-9. So what do you want to match in the first place? What are false positives you are getting? What are examples of strings you are matching against?

Comment: This question is very unclear. The first expr and the code below do not match.

Comment: You want to use `r''` raw strings to avoid all the doubled `\\`, and there is a `re.VERBOSE` mode to make writing readable expressions easer than concatenating 9 separate strings..

Comment: `print rg.pattern` would help you to check the resulting regex.

Comment: Why are you wasting time capturing individual substrings if you're just going to concatenate them all back together again?  Just do `txt2 = '"' + m.group(0) + '"'`.

Comment: May be worth taking a read of this https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Comment: ``\d+`` isn't the pattern for one digit, it is for "one or a succession of digits"

Comment: All of this, is the feedback I was hoping to find. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this code, based on what I see in your question:

```
import re

pat = ('([2-9])'        # Integer Number 1
       '([p-z])'        # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 1
       '([a-h])'        # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 2
       '([2-9])'        # Integer Number 2
       '([a-z]*[p-z]+)' # Word 1
       '([2-9])'        # Integer Number 3
       '([p-z])'        # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 3
       '(.)'            # Any Single Character 1
       '([p-z])'        # Any Single Word Character (Not Whitespace) 4
       )
rg = re.compile(pat)

txt = 'jiji4pa6fmlgkfmoaz8p#q,,,,,,,,,,'
m = rg.search(txt)
if m:
    text2 = "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s" % m.groups()
    print text2

# prints 4pa6fmlgkfmoaz8p#q
```

## EDIT

```
text2 = ''.join(m.groups())  # is better
```

Comment: Based on other comments the \d is still matching every integer. Would't it be more specific to use ([2-9]) instead?

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry. I copied from the series of re1,re2,etc but you're right: if you doesn't want digits 0 and 1, you must use ``[2-9]`` instead of ``\d``. I corrected my code

Comment: @Mondrianaire Thank you. I doesn't know where was my brain today; I edited my answer to give a simpler way to obtain the result in the case of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the range 2-9 in Python, like so: `re1 = re.compile(r'[2-9]')`. A test in my console then showed that `re1.match('7')` returns a `MatchObject` as you want, whereas `re1.match('0')` returns `None`, also as you want.

You also appear to have used the range `[a-z]` in `re2`, where you said you wanted `[p-z]` - similar issues in the other character ranges.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that the expression I was using was a lot more lenient that I wanted to be, I was unsure if using [2-9] was correct syntax for python.